# Retrieving two levels of data with a single call to the SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, database-design

I need to retrieve a set of records from db and attach them to `List<FirstRecord>` variable.  However, each `FirstRecord` object has a set of `SecondRecord` objects, so I also need to define a variable like `List<SecondRecord>`.

Currently, to do that, first I make a call to DB to build the `List<FirstRecord>` variable, then for each `FirstRecord`, I make another DB call to retrieve the data and build the `List<SecondRecord>` variable for each `FirstRecord` object.

Of course, this is a very weak design. I am using SQL Helper. Is it possible to handle this task with a single call to the db? Or, do you think that Entity Framework can handle this, and I should better switch to Entity Framework?

UPDATED WITH AN EXAMPLE

TABLE1
UserId | UserName
1422   | erkaner

TABLE2
PostId | Text     | UserId 
1      | messge1  | 1422 
1      | messge2  | 1422 
1      | messge3  | 1422

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public Guid UserId{set ; get ;}

    public string Username {set ; get ;}

    public List<PostInfo> Posts {set ; get ;}   
}

public class PostInfo
{
    public Guid PostId{set ; get ;}

    public string PostText{set ; get ;}   
}
```

Then, I should use inner join to merge TABLE1 and TABLE2 and retrieve all data at once. Then, with appropriate coding I should create the UserInfo object and the List obhect inside it. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe your database schema?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to display this data.  More description of the project is needed.

Comment: why don't just fetch all the records in one go and use linq to create your structure.

Comment: I updated the post, did I get it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much sure if this will be appropriate but why not make `SecondRecord` a instance member of `FirstRecord` like

```
public class SecondRecord
{
  //properties

  //Methods
}


public class FirstRecord
{
  public SecondRecord secondRecord;
}
```

Then you can get all `FirstRecord` and `secondrecord` together from database and populate accordingly which will avoid making a double call to the DB.

Per your edited post; Yes, that's what should be done. Since you already have a relationship between the tables, you can do a `leftjoin` on `userid` column (since every user may/may not have a post necessarily) and get all records and then fill the `userinfo` and `postinfo` accordingly.

```
select t1.userid, 
t1.username,
t2.postid,
t2.text
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Comment: Yes, that's what should be done. Since you already have a relationship between the tables, you can do a `join` on `userid` column and get all records and then fill the userinfo and postinfo object accordingly.

Comment: thank you! what if I have another set of objects similar to PostInfo. Lets say each UserInfo object will have 1 or more PostInfo objects, 1 or more BadgeInfo object, so forth? Then, should I still follow the same approach?

Comment: You can, I don't see any issue with that unless the complexity is becoming too high.

Answer (score 2):

Use inner join in your query to get all the data and then in code you can fill your lists with that data. This will hit SQL only one time.

Also,Entity FrameWork will provide you what you need.

It will be your decision to switch to EF or not.

Comment: Yes you are right. but why you need UserID in postInfo?